# Cannot set property at eval - Firebase Storage with Vue

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js

Uploading a file to firebase successfully so far.
Now we are taking that files url and trying to do something with it but I think I'm getting stuck in a .then rabbit hole.

I have my data portion set up like so:

```
  data: () => ({
fileURL: "",
fileToUpload: null, //set from a file input
  }),
```

The portion of code I am running after clicking an upload button is:

```
      var uploadTask = fb.storage().ref("/inventory/" + this.fileToUpload.name);
  uploadTask.put(this.fileToUpload).then(() => {
    uploadTask.getDownloadURL().then(function (url) {
      this.fileURL = url; //this is the problem...
    });
  });
```

Not sure how I can successfully set fileURL without getting a warning.

> Uncaught (in promise)
> TypeError: Cannot set property 'fileURL' of undefined
> at eval

Any advise much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is likely that the scope of the `this` keyword has changed because you put it inside of an additional function.

The easiest way to solve this is to use an arrow function, which doesn't have its own `this` scope.

```js
var uploadTask = fb.storage().ref("/inventory/" + this.fileToUpload.name);
  uploadTask.put(this.fileToUpload).then(() => {
    uploadTask.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
      this.fileURL = url;
    });
});
```